# Download html window object with JS

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, download, jspdf

i have this iframe here, and i want to doanload the window page with pdf inside, js function print() only shows the page, i want to download it automatically, bellow is the full code (i tryed with jspdf too).

```
<iframe id="conteudoIframe" src="https://eproc.trf4.jus.br/eproc2trf4/controlador.php?acao=acessar_documento_publico&doc=41625504719486351366932807019&evento=20084&key=0562cc6eddee0cc4a81dd869f92328dceab34deeaa59f4a33c43da6361cf42d6&hash=08920b364dc8433ad071d6b10c7e3817"  name="superior" width="100%" height="560px"></iframe>

<script>

    downloadPdfFromIframe();

    function downloadPdfFromIframe() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js';
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        script.onload = () => { setTimeout(download(), 20000); };

        function download() {

            var myIframe = document.getElementById("conteudoIframe").contentWindow;

            myIframe.focus();
            myIframe.print();
            myIframe.close();

            var pdf = new jsPDF();

            pdf.fromHTML(myIframe);
            pdf.save('test.pdf');

            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: iframe src url may expires, if so, i will edit the question and paste another one

Comment: Do you have the permission to access the iframe content? What do you want to download? Print() is not the same as download. If you print a page it should also print iframes.

Comment: i can print the content, when i do it, show the pdf document, so, if print() have this function, i just want to download this printed page automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iframes are only a window to remote objects thus while viewing they are showing both the already downloaded html surround and the already downloaded PDF but the PDF is independent It may be downloaded before or after the frame, you can see the pdf behind the print html dialog. So the PDF is in a different application as seen in the second browser view of your HTML.

Thus you have to save/print ***either one at a time***. Frame object or Pdf object, to get both is not impossible, just needs to be done with a suitable application (not browser). So just like here I have ScreenShots, those canvases can be easily saved or printed as PDF.

***A Chrome based Browser viewing the iFrame*** for printing

[image]

***A Firefox based Browser viewing the iFrame*** to print using any other method like open in a second application window.

[image: ![enter image description here]

If you need to download the two parts outside a browser then use two Download Commands so here is my.pdf

[image]

```
curl -o my.pdf "https://eproc.trf4.jus.br/eproc2trf4/controlador.php?acao=acessar_documento_implementacao&doc=41625504719486351366932807019&evento=20084&key=0562cc6eddee0cc4a81dd869f92328dceab34deeaa59f4a33c43da6361cf42d6&hash=08920b364dc8433ad071d6b10c7e3817&termosPesquisados="
```

Comment: ok thank you for the explanation, i just want tosave de pdf, pdf object or frame object, using js or other programing language.

Comment: i have already tried with c#, but using webclinet or httpclient the document does not opens, give me error, thats why i decided do it with js.

Comment: OBS: the igrame url expires every 3 hours, i alwas update it here by editing the Question

Comment: i used your cmd comand, but the pdf does not open, here is the command: curl -o my.pdf "https://eproc.trf4.jus.br/eproc2trf4/controlador.php?acao=acessar_documento_publico&doc=41625504719486351366932807019&evento=20084&key=d3d4c40217d515a89ce5702fecd4a85448febf9aae4d8a2f0796b816174999f2&hash=06d5efd6863c6229b4099822e36f2237"

Comment: its working, i changed the url to be the same with your example: curl -o my.pdf "https://eproc.trf4.jus.br/eproc2trf4/controlador.php?acao=acessar_documento_implementacao&doc=41625504719486351366932807019&evento=20084&key=d3d4c40217d515a89ce5702fecd4a85448febf9aae4d8a2f0796b816174999f2&hash=06d5efd6863c6229b4099822e36f2237&termosPesquisados="

Comment: now i understood, the first link: https://eproc.trf4.jus.br/eproc2trf4/controlador.php?acao=acessar_documento_publico&doc=41625504719486351366932807019&evento=20084&key=50cdbe12917a12afb875c419c04d2280cdf99e618604f40150f6248a6b5ce10d&hash=248fe3bd68e1630b7ec828dd9c59bc9d is a link that shows the iframe wit the pdf, but this iframe has a source with another url, where is the real document, getting this url from the iframe and putting https://eproc.trf4.jus.br/eproc2trf4/ before, workes perfetly, i can ow downaload it directly from my c# code, thanks you very much